# Bash Script in Ubuntu ': not a valid identifierkage

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I ran the following script using ". setup_package.sh", and get the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/dj/$ . setup_package.sh
: command not found
: command not found
Need to install packages? (ex: Y/N):
': not a valid identifierkage
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

File:

```
#!/bin/bash

###
# read project input
###

echo "Need to install packages? (ex: Y/N): "
read install_package
```

Comment: You lack some information, try editing the script and add `set -x` add the top, below the sheebang. This will output the exact commands that are generated.

Answer (score 0):

`setup_package.sh` contains windows line endings. You should install `dos2unix` and run:

```
dos2unix setup_package.sh
```